# Apex trigger to create record through data loader and assign to the related list of account

Tags: trigger

I am importing data into Account object through data loader.I want that the contact that i imported to the contact object should automatically assign to the Account Name (that is given in the account Name of  contact) and contact should be shown in the assign account related list. Would i need to write a trigger for this and how i can write trigger for automatically assign contact in account related list

Comment: Do you have duplicate Account names in Account CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

No need to write any automation for your requirement. Please follow guidelines for importing Accounts and contacts in Salesforce through data loader.

1. Import the Account records.
2. Export those newly created records or maintain the success file of imported records (It will include the recently created record Id (i.e AccountId)).
3. Use VLOOKUP to create a new contact CSV file which matches the contacts with the exact account ID.
4. Import the contact records.

It will associate the existing account with newly created contact records and you will see the related list of associated contacts on Account record.